# Where to put alias commands for use in Windows 7

Tags: window, alias

I know you can add alias commands in Linux to the `.bashrc` file, but Window 7 definitely does not use bash.

Where and how can I add alias commands for use in the command prompt `cmd.exe`?

Answer (score 1):

The alias command is not available in DOS (or the cmd.exe phaux DOS). There are some options, but generally you're going to have to use doskey, make a `.bat` file to handle your command, or do a registry edit (hack).

[Here are some options.](http://www.rhyous.com/2010/10/20/adding-an-alias-in-windows-7-or-making-ls-dir-in-a-command-prompt/)